# Checking of Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

My textbook requires a subspace to meet the following three criteria:

For a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, $W$ is subspace if and only if

1) $x+y \in W\;$ $\forall x,y$ in $W$

2) $ax \in W\;$ $\forall a \in F\;\; \forall x \in W$

3) $0 \in W$

but is it okay for me to check only whether

4) $ax+y \in W$ $\forall x,y \in W$ and $\forall a \in F$?

I think 4) could result in problems if F does not contain $1$

4) may or may not work depending on the which Field is used.

What do you think?

Comment: I think fields always contain 1. I also think the empty set satisfies (4).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh really? how does one could understand what the field is? I thought field is completely arbitrary choice of one individual to handle vectorspace

Comment: Fields are fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown my highness, then there's no field without 1?

Comment: Yes Dasschin - a $field$ is a commutative division ring. See this link -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html, and refer to property 8 (also see the comment defining a field towards the bottom); note we can also say a field is a commutative division algebra.  The "1" in any field you are referring to is the (unique) $identity$ element. Without an identity element, the ring collapses (and so would the field); i.e., a field axiom states if $F$ is a field, then there exists a (unique) element $1_{F}\in F$ such that for all $x\in F$ we have $1_{F}x=x$

Comment: Another field axiom says that for every $x\in F\big\backslash\{0_{F}\}$ (meaning $x\in F$ and $x\neq 0_{F}$), there exists a (unique) inverse element (that we choose to write as) $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1_{F}$. The subscript refers to dependence of the set that may be a field if $all$ field axioms are satisfied (similar to a set being a vector space if $all$ vector-space axioms are satisfied).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. A sufficient criterion for a nonempty subset $W$ being a subspace is that $y-ax \in W$, for all $x, y \in W$ and for all $a \in F$.

To show $y+x \in W$, take $a=-1$. To show $0 \in W$, take $a=1$, and then use the fact that $x-ax \in W$. Lastly, we need that $cx \in W$ for all $c \in F$, which may be done by letting $y=0$. Then we have $y-(-c)x=cx \in W$, by the previous properties.

Comment: It looks like your notion already assuming that field always contain 1. Is that correct?

Comment: @Daschin Fields always contain one. By definition, a field $F$ is a ring with unity such that $0 \neq 1$, where $F-\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication. This last condition is what we want out of a field, but if we don't have $1$ then we can't invert things

Comment: @Daschin I also realized that your formulation is correct, but regardless the proof is the essentially the same

Comment: @leibewtz What is ring? I mean I am now a freshman year of undergraduate. ring is the concept of like more advanced level algebra?

Comment: @Daschin Wikipedia can help with questions like these, but roughly a ring is a set together with two compatible operations, usually called $+$ and $*$, such that we may always add, subtract, and multiply, but not always divide. For example, consider the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$. We can add things and subtract in $\mathbb{Z}$ but we can't divide by $2$, say.